# Adding style stored in a variable inside React class

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to use some style inside my React class. I have done it before doing:

```
<div style={{background: "red"}}></div>
```

I want to use a variable instead, for example:

```
<div style={divStyle}></div>
```

My code looks like:

```
class HolaMundo extends React.Component {
  const divStyle = {
    color: 'blue',
  };
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="container" style={divStyle}> 
        <h1> Hola {this.props.name}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<HolaMundo name="One" />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

But the styles are not applied. How can I achieve this?

Comment: That should work. What's the issue?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a static class variable?

Comment: I don't know what is going on, I'm working on codepen and is not recognizing the styles :(

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't define a constant in the middle of a class, that's invalid syntax. Class bodies, by definition<sup>1</sup>, can only contain method definitions, static method definitions, and empty statements (`;`)<sup>2</sup>. Define the `divStyle` inside a method:

```
class HolaMundo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const divStyle = {
            color: 'blue',
        };

        return (
          <div className="container" style={divStyle}> 
            <h1>Hola {this.props.name}</h1>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Per the ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification, [Section 14.5 - Class Definitions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-class-definitions)

<sup>2</sup>[Babel](https://babeljs.io) currently supports class properties (with [plugins](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)). You can also assign an instance variable through the constructor, with `this.style = { ... }` and access it anywhere in the class with `this.style`.

Comment: Thank you it works now :), The thing is that it wasn't printing any errors on the console ( im working on codepen)

Comment: and does it make any difference if i do it the way you showed me or any the bottom of the page?

Comment: @FidelCastro Codepen may be suppressing errors. If you declare the constant outside of the class, it's okay, but I'd recommend declaring a variable at the narrowest scope possible. If there's no need to declare it outside the class, I wouldn't.

Answer (score 5):

At the bottom of the page (below the class declaration) you can define a styles object:

```
 const styles = {
  exampleStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  }
};
```

then pass it into a components style prop:

```
style={styles.exampleStyle}
```

I prefer doing it like this as you can then keep all your styles for the component in one object rather than having a styles object for each of your methods in the class.