# Pass duplicated css property to tags style

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to write 2 values of the same css property in react. I can make a string:

```
`height: ${this.props.height + 1}px; height: calc(${this.props.height}px + var(--d));`
```

but react does not accept string as style.

So what should I pass?

```
<div style={whatShouldIPlaceHere} />
```

Comment: Can I ask why you want to apply duplicate values?  Only one will actually be applied on render.

Comment: Looks like you're doing legacy browser fallbacks. Is that correct? And does this cover your case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260533/adding-style-stored-in-a-variable-inside-react-class

Comment: Actually that makes sense.  However styles are objects in React, so it will not allow duplicate keys.  Maybe [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/) can help?  Almost every browser from the last decade will support ```calc```, but I'm sure there are some that don't.  Good question!

Comment: This comment thread might shed some light: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6467

Do you reeeeaaaally need duplicate styles for fallback, though? If so, maybe checkout styled-components or CSS Modules.

Comment: @RutherfordWonkington, `calc` is not a problem, but [css variables](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) are.

Comment: @isherwood, no, I don't have syntax errors in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution with `cssText` property.
It seems working, but actually typescript doesn't agree that such property exists...

```
<div style={{ cssText: `height: ${this.props.height + 1}px; height: calc(${this.props.height}px + var(--d));` }} />
```